# Google map integration with blackberry

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, dictionary

I want to integrate Google map in my blackberry native application. And my requirements are:

1. searching nearest location
2. Pin the location on map
3. Tapping on any pin, a small pop-up will be displayed where User can view detailed
   description
4. The tool tip showing the address should be interactive.

Something similar to image attached. Guide me with the samples to achieve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GMLocation location example

```
GMLocation location = new GMLocation(51.507778, -0.128056, "London");
invokeGMaps(location);
```

**invokeGMaps method**

```
public void invokeGMaps(GMLocation l) {
        int mh = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("GoogleMaps");
        if (mh == 0) {
            try {
                throw new ApplicationManagerException("GoogleMaps isn't installed");
            } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        RichTextField rich = new RichTextField("fhfdjdytdytd"+ mh);
        add(rich);
        URLEncodedPostData uepd = new URLEncodedPostData(null, false);
        uepd.append("action", "LOCN");
        uepd.append("a", "@latlon:" + l.getLatitude() + "," + l.getLongitude());
        uepd.append("title", l.getName());
        uepd.append("description", l.getDescription());

        String[] args = { "http://gmm/x?" + uepd.toString() };
        RichTextField rich1 = new RichTextField("l.getName()"+ l.getName());
        add(rich1);
        ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(mh)[0];
        ApplicationDescriptor ad2 = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, args);
        try {
            ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ad2, true);
        } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**GMLocation class**

```
public class GMLocation {    
String mName;
String mDescription;
double mLatitude;
double mLongitude;
public GMLocation(double lat, double lon) {
    mLatitude = lat;
    mLongitude = lon;
}    
public GMLocation(double d, double e, String name) {
    this(d, e);
    mName = name;
}    
public GMLocation(double lat, double lon, String name, String descr) {
    this(lat, lon, name);
    mDescription = descr;
}    
public String getName() {
    return mName;
}    
public String getDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}    
public String getLongitude() {
    return String.valueOf(mLongitude);
}    
public String getLatitude() {
    return String.valueOf(mLatitude);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Using this approach this invokes the google map application. Any other way to integrate the same inside my application rather depending on other application?

Comment: Tthan i think you can use google map url in brouserfield.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#URL_Parameters this link is use for this